# The deploy has failed with error: Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xx.xx: npm exit status: 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, npm-install

I hope you are well, I have a rather complex problem in my project, when trying to perform a deployment, it does not allow me because when it reaches the npm:install section, it throws me the following error.

`the error after running cap production deploy --trace`:

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => npm:install
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx: npm exit status: 1
npm stdout: Nothing written
npm stderr: Nothing written
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [a13891cd] Running [ -d /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/uploads ] as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx

 DEBUG [a13891cd] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/uploads ]

 DEBUG [a13891cd] Finished in 0.530 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

  INFO [84a96456] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/shared/public/uploads /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/uploads as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx

 DEBUG [84a96456] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.7" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/shared/public/uploads /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/uploads )

  INFO [84a96456] Finished in 0.511 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [7ee40206] Running [ -L /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/assets ] as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx

 DEBUG [7ee40206] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/assets ]

 DEBUG [7ee40206] Finished in 0.432 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

 DEBUG [9bb0c376] Running [ -d /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/assets ] as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx

 DEBUG [9bb0c376] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/assets ]

 DEBUG [9bb0c376] Finished in 0.446 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

  INFO [0b89ab98] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/assets as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx

 DEBUG [0b89ab98] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.7" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121/public/assets )

  INFO [0b89ab98] Finished in 0.429 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [d1380a67] Running if test ! -d /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@xxxxx_xxxxx

 DEBUG [d1380a67] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx/releases/20230525164121'" 1>&2; false; fi
```

`production.rb`:

```
set :stage, :production
set :branch, "main"
server "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", user: "deploy", roles: %w[app db web]
```

`deploy.rb`:

```
lock "~> 3.17.1"

set :application, "xxxxxx"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:x-xxx/xxxxxx_xxxxx.git"

set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/xxxxx_xxxxx"

append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads"


Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 3



namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  task :seed do
    on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, "db:seed"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
ruby -v = 2.7.7
```

I have tried many solutions but still can't find a true one, change my droplet, I have enough resources and install new versions.

Comment: Do not just add errors or code as screenshots. Instead, please edit your question and add the full error message from your screenshot as actual text to it.